# Net Core 3.0 cann't see appsettings.Production.json file

Tags: .net, environment-variables

I have dotnet core angular Project. In my project I have **appsettings.json** and **appsettings.Production.json** files and I put connection string like this:

**appsettings.json**

`"ConnectionStrings": { "Default": "server=localhost\\sqlins01; database=realstate; Integrated Security=SSPI" },`

**appsettings.Production.json**

`"ConnectionStrings": { "Default": "server=.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com,1433; User=realstate; password=realstate; Initial Catalog=realstate" },`

and I Change **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT** to production as

[image]

When I run `dotnet ef update database`, it updates local database. but when I change the connection string in **appsettings.json** with the production one, it updates aws rds (production) database.

My question is why dotnet cann't found **appsettings.Production.json**

Comment: Are you running the `dotnet ef` command from the same directory the JSON file is located in? And in the terminal, is `echo %ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT%` correct? (If not, you need to restart the terminal for the environment variable change to take effect.)

Comment: echo result is Develpment

Comment: @JanJoneš even after I restart the terminal, echo result shows Development

Comment: You probably haven't restarted the terminal properly, then. Maybe you can just change the environment variable from inside the terminal, then you won't need to restart it. Use [set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/set_1) command `set ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production` before running the `dotnet ef` command.